# react native build error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I had to completely rewrite the question.

I have a react native android app. When I built the `apk` file with `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`, it went fine, but after that it stopped compiling at all. Even `react-native run-android` is not working anymore.

What I found so far:
First, the error is this

```
Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

If I add these lines to `gradle.properties`,

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

the error changes. Now it's this

```
Task :@JWWon_react-native-universal-pedometer:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
cannot find symbol
  private void sendPedometerUpdateEvent(@Nullable WritableMap params) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class BMDPedometerModule
```

The problem is not with the library though. If I remove it from the project, it start complaining about another one. To get it to compile, I have to remove 7 libraries. An example:

```
Task :@react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
error: package android.support.v4.net does not exist
import android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat;
error: cannot find symbol
    promise.resolve(ConnectivityManagerCompat.isActiveNetworkMetered(getConnectivityManager()));
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ConnectivityManagerCompat
  location: class ConnectivityReceiver
2 errors
```

then if I remove another, this happens:

```
Task :react-native-camera-kit:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
                                 ^
package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.IntRange;
                                 ^
...
92 errors
```

So it will compile if I remove 7 libraries from the project. They are:

`react-native-camera-kit
@react-native-community_netinfo
react-native-push-notification
react-native-sensors
@JWWon_react-native-universal-pedometer
react-native-keep-awake
react-native-toast-native`

Without them, it compiles perfectly. So there's a bigger problem that doesn't let it work. 2 days ago, all of those libraries were working perfectly with no problem. But now something crushes it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      bla bla bla...
  }
  subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                details.useVersion "12.+"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                details.useVersion "+"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**add subprojects in build.gradle (android)**

```
dependencies {
     ...bla bla bla

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+"
}
```

**add implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+" in build.gradle (android/app)**

**so you don't need to migrate to Androidx**

edit 1: code format

edit 2: missing a bracket

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I am looking for a solution without android x. I've tried your suggestion. It finds the resources from now, but now there's a problem with library react-native-push-notification. I guess it needs another version of gcm and crashes. Can you give me a hint how to fix that?

Comment: try this

https://pastebin.com/MdKfhPYG

change in resolutionStrategy.eachDependency block

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, man! I'm so grateful. God bless you!

Answer (score 70):

Try with jetifier

`npm install --save-dev jetifier`
Or use yarn, but install it locally in your project, not globally

`npx jetify`
or
`npx jetify -w=1` - to specify the number of parallel workers

`npx react-native run-android`

Comment: these steps work. i use yarn add jetifier then yarn jetify  and react-native run-android

Answer (score 37):

I actually had something very similar happen and running this worked

```
npx jetify
```

When I ran it through the CI pipeline it didn't work and ended having to add

```
"scripts": {
 ...
    "postinstall": "jetify"
}
```

After npm runs install in the pipeline it then run jetify to convert to androidx and covers all the libraries that need to be converted.

Comment: lifesaver for me

Comment: just npx jetify was enough for me, thanks

Comment: npx jetify worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

try to use androidx

```
// build.gradle 
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

// where use it
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

UPDATE:

if other libraries error, maybe you can try [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#usage-for-source-files),
I know it by this helpful [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/issues/107#issuecomment-503819819).

the full reference is below, hope helpful : )

```
// android/build.gradle
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 24
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "1.0.0-beta01"
}

// app/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9"  // From node_modules
}
```

by the way, I meet this problem(AndroidX) for a few days, at last, solve it by update `react-native@0.59.9`, use the latest android setting and the magic [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#usage-for-source-files).

Comment: I tried this. I think it worked, but my project still doesn't compile, I have another error with another library. I added this to the question

Comment: As far as I understand, it fixed the error. But because now I'm using Android X, another library doesn't work anymore

Comment: I upgraded to react-native 0.59.9, and then experimented with other stuff. So I got it working by unlinking 5 libraries from the project. I updated the question. If I try to link it back, it doesn't work anymore. Can you please look it up?

Comment: I think you can choose to change the library or fork it. At least, `@react-native-community_netinfo react-native-push-notification react-native-keep-awake`, these three libraries would work perfectly after `jetifier` process : )

Comment: amazing, my old code `import android.support.annotation.Nullable;`, change to `import androidx.annotation.Nullable;`. it works now

Answer (score 0):

// build.gradle

implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

// where use it

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

Improt missing classes from androidx at all places getting error.

Answer (score -1):

add

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in gradle.properties

Answer (score -1):

Okay. It was pain in the ass for last 4 days, but I got it working for now.

What I did:

added

`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`
to gradle.properties

Changed sdk to 28

`compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

And removed one library `react-native-camera-kit`. It all compiles now at least. Jetifier doesn't work with this library I guess. For now I have to turn it off.